# Ruby installation (2.2.2) fails in macOS Big Sur

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I am running into some trouble installing Ruby 2.2.2 on macOS Big Sur. Has anyone had a similar issue that they were able to resolve? Many thanks

Error:

```
`Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /Users/findum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2

Downloading ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.2...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.2 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.1 using ruby-build 20201225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/x8/g8yqvrh55gq0wds4hny1t94r0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210101111906.42540.uFRvAN
Results logged to /var/folders/x8/g8yqvrh55gq0wds4hny1t94r0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210101111906.42540.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/parser.c
linking shared-object json/ext/parser.bundle
linking shared-object pathname.bundle
installing default psych libraries
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
linking shared-object bigdecimal.bundle
linking shared-object psych.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2`
```

Comment: Trying to install using this command: `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 2.2.2`

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting the log file mentioned in the error message /var/folders/x8/g8yqvrh55gq0wds4hny1t94r0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210101111906.42540.log. It might have additional info that could be helpful.

Comment: See my updated answer. I don't use rbenv or ruby-build so can't speak to its efficacy.

Comment: "*WARNING: ruby-2.2.2 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.*" Do you specifically need Ruby 2.2.2?

Comment: Thank you @Schwern ! Yes, I am working on rebooting an older project. Learning how to upgrade to a newer Ruby version :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### EDIT

It looks like OP edited the error in the original message so the below answer is no longer relevant. Leaving it here for posterity.

---

### Updated Answer

Based on discussion in a couple of Github issues on the rbenv repo,

- https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1480
- https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1489

it sounds like Apple changed the default `CFLAGS` as part of xcode 12, which makes some of the native extension installations go haywire. It sounds like the solution proposed in those issues is

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.2.2
```

---

### Original answer

The error states it failed due to issues with extensions

```
The Ruby readline extension was not compiled.
The Ruby zlib extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
```

so I would suggest trying to install those extensions manually first, then retrying the ruby install.

With brew:

```
brew install readline
brew install zlib
```

There are some issues on `ruby-build`'s github that might help as well:

- https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1076
- https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/832#issuecomment-160906530

Comment: Thank you @supremebeing7! I ran both `brew install readline
brew install zlib` but, it looks like they are already installed and up-to-date. I reinstalled both readline and zlib, but still no luck :(

Comment: Same error after reinstalling? How about using the commands from the linked github issues, e.g. `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" --with-zlib-dir="$(brew --prefix zlib)"`

Comment: Oh wait, it looks like you updated the error message in your post?

Comment: Ah! I am sorry– I am new to Stack Overflow! I should have kept the original error.  The original error was with Ruby readline/zlib. Error evolved to current description. `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.2.2` solved the problem! Thank you so much for your help, @supremebeing7 !