# rbenv build failures macos

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

When trying to use rbenv to install a new ruby version, I keep getting build failures on Mac OS:

```
trevoraron@Trevor-Aron api % rbenv install 2.6.7                            
Downloading ruby-2.6.7.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.7.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.7...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.3.1 using ruby-build 20220426)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/pk/y07ms18x3l98w09j6dj4p_680000gn/T/ruby-build.20220606121206.1319.GLeYbo
Results logged to /var/folders/pk/y07ms18x3l98w09j6dj4p_680000gn/T/ruby-build.20220606121206.1319.log

Last 10 log lines:
219 warnings generated.
193 warnings generated.
201 warnings generated.
384 warnings generated.
219 warnings generated.
306 warnings generated.
201 warnings generated.
271 warnings generated.
217 warnings generated.
261 warnings generated.
```

I'm running on x86

Comment: The error message says that results have been logged to `/var/folders/pk/y07ms18x3l98w09j6dj4p_680000gn/T/ruby-build.20220606121206.1319.log`. Did you look at that file? Does it contain anything interesting?

Comment: There are many possible solutions, but it's difficult to know what to suggest from so little information. For example, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71029144/1954610).

Answer (score 24):

Are you trying to install in a M1? I had a similar issue and fixed by running:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS='--with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline/' arch -x86_64 rbenv install 3.1.2
```

Comment: This worked for me with M1 macOS Monterey Ver.12.5 for installing Ruby-3.1.2. This answer looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71029144/3577922

Comment: It did not work for me in M1 macOS Monterrey 12.6